# Latitude,longitude and geographical quarter (NW, NE, SW, SE) from a center to a given point

Tags: gps, geometry, geocoding, geospatial, geo

Considering latitude and longitude, I was looking for a way to know in which quarter is located a point from a given center.

```
NW             NE
  ......|......
  ..X...|......
  ......|......
  ------x------
  ......|......
  ......|......
  ......|......
SW             SE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the poles and antimeridian (where longitude = +/- 180), it's  straightforward:

```
if(lat > centerLat)
  if(long < centerLong)
    NW
  if(long > centerLong
    NE

if(lat < centerLat)
  if(long < centerLong)
    SW
  if(long > centerLong
    SE
```

If you need it to work near the antimeridian, translate your whole system east by adding 180 degrees to all the longitudes.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the bearing from center to point in degrees (search for aviation formula homepage). Then if bearing in range [0,90): NE,
[90,180) -> SE. same for both other directions.
[180,270) -> SW
[270, 360) -> NW

You can simplyfy the check by

```
double bearing = bearing(latCenter, lonCenter, lat, lon);
int index = bearing / 90;
String[] quadrants = new String[] {"NE", "SE", "SW", NW"};

String result = quadrant[index];
```